# Is there Some Good document or article to get info on how to identify Hyper ledger Peers IP dynamically

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

As of now I have used confix tx generator to generate config material of muliple peers and have changed the createPeerAdmin card to include the IP address of all Peer nodes so that connection.json file produced contains the IP address of all the peer nodes in my network , Is there a way in which i can add 1 more peer node and it could be connected with my already running network.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. 
You should read about [service discovery feature](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/discovery-overview.html).
There are client side APIs in the SDKs you can use to utilize this feature and have the peers be selected dynamically.